# swift enums w Objective-C typedefs in Kotlin

Tags: objective-c, swift, kotlin, enums

i'm moving some business logic from iOS into Kotlin and this construct seems strange to me

```
// AttachmentType.h
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, AttachmentType) {
    AttachmentType1 = 0,
    AttachmentType2 = 1,
    AttachmentType3 = 2
}


// PhotoType.swift
enum PhotoType {
    case t1(AttachmentType1), t2(AttachmentType1), t3(AttachmentType1)

    var attachmentType: AttachmentType {
        switch self {
        case .t1(let type):
            return type
        case .t3(let type):
            return type
        case .t3(let type):
            return type
        }
    }
}
```

what i'm confused about here is the ivar `attachmentType`

1. is this essentially a variable of type `AttachmentType`?
2. does this allow all 9 permutations of the two types. eg: can i instantiate a PhotoType that represents AttachmentType1 with t1, AttachmentType1 with t2, AttachmentType1 with t3, AttachmentType2 with t1, etc...
3. what is the equivalent construct for Kotlin? 9 sealed classes?

Answer (score 1):

1. `PhotoType` uses an enum ["associated value"](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148)
2. it does allow the 9 cases to be created in a type-safe way.
3. the following structure in Kotlin achieves the same goal:

```

```
sealed class PhotoType {
  abstract val type: AttachmentType
}

data class t1(override val type: AttachmentType) : PhotoType()
data class t2(override val type: AttachmentType) : PhotoType()
data class t3(override val type: AttachmentType) : PhotoType()
```

```